# How to show error when user input full with number

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material

I have an angular/material form, where I have an input type `number`.

Since I am in Asia, user can input full width digit, but I would like to show an error saying "half-width only".

I made the following

component

```typescript
const CustomValidator = {
  fullWidthNumber(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    console.log(control.value);
    return control.value.toString().match(/[\uff00-\uff9f]/) ? { fullWidth: true } : null;
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
  title = 'MyShopApp';

  public altitudeControl: FormControl;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.altitudeControl = new FormControl(2, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.min(5),
        Validators.max(10),
        CustomValidator.fullWidthNumber,
      ]);
  }
}
```

template

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="altitudeControl.valid && setHeight(altitudeControl.value)">
    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <mat-label>{{ "ALTITUDE"  }}</mat-label>
        <input matInput [formControl]="altitudeControl" name="altitude" type="number" />
        <mat-error *ngIf="altitudeControl.hasError('max')">
            ERROR.FIELD.MAX
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="altitudeControl.hasError('min')">
            ERROR.FIELD.MIN
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="altitudeControl.hasError('fullWidth')"> ERROR.FIELD.FULL_WIDTH </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="altitudeControl.hasError('required')">
            ERROR.FIELD.REQUIRED
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

The problem is, when I add a full digit like １２３, the content is removed, and the error never trigger.

How can I achieve it ?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-form-group-validation-8ggfr3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: You might want to add some examples of half-width and full-width that you want to be valid/invalid. Some of us are not familiar with this.

Comment: １２３ => invalid
123 => valid

Comment: In your Stackblitz there is not chance to type 1 2 3, because it's not number.

Comment: that's what my question is about, how do I do ?

Comment: inputType="number" only accepts numbers, obviously. "1 2 3" is not a number. I think you should remove the inputtype and write your own validator that allows "1 2 3"

Answer (score 1):

So as far as I understand it, the validation works this way:

- 1 2 3 => invalid
- 123 => valid

As Robin Dijkhof mentioned, 1 2 3 is not a number but a string - which is why your `<input type="number"/>` does not allow it.

What I'm personally wondering about is why you want to allow 1 2 3, just to then show an invalid form error? In the end this is the point of having html standards like `type="number"` because this way the browser can take the validation effort from you.

If I don't understand the use case correctly, and you have to implement it this way, here is an approach I can think of:

- Change your input to `type="text"`
- Write custom validators for:

  - fullWidthNumber for stringified number
  - Min length of stringified number
  - Max length of stringified number

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand why you wish to do this, as many people doesn't know why their input doesn't work when they typed in Full Width Numbers. To fix this, you will need to write a custom converter or checks. (like using switch statement for every full width numbers, or use range check if it is using unicode, See [this wiki for the code id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_Fullwidth_Forms_(Unicode_block)))

However, you will need to change the input types to text as on default, type="number" will cut out all non half length numbers / characters automatically.

The regex for filtering out the Full Length Numbers is:

```
[\uFF10-\uFF19]
```

Where [\uFF10] is "０" and [\uFF19] is "９". Note that in newer version, you can just type it in directly like this:

```
[０-９] //ONLY WORK IN NEWER VERSIONS
```

The unicode standard also allows you to subtract each char code by FEE0 to convert Full Width From to standard ASCII form. Note that it only works on char in range [\uFF01-\uFF5E].